# How can I pass two option arrays for the same dropdown component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dropdown

I want to reuse my dropdown component in two other containers by passing two different set of array.

**Example:** One dropdown menu used for creating a breakfast option menu and the other for dinner option menu.

I've tried creating two arrays in state part of the class. but when i call the array it shows no options

```
class DropDownDropper extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {options: [
        breakfast: [
          { label: "Location 1", value: 1 },
          { label: "Location 2", value: 2 },
          { label: "Location 3", value: 3 },
          { label: "Location 4", value: 4 },
          { label: "Location 5", value: 5 },
          { label: "Location 6", value: 6 },
        ] , 
        dinner: [
          { labe: "Venue 1", value: 1 },
          { labe: "Venue 2", value: 1 },
          { labe: "Venue 3", value: 1 },
          { labe: "Venue 4", value: 1 },
          { labe: "Venue 5", value: 1 },
      ]
        ]
    }
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <Select options = { this.props.options
           } />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your syntax: `options: [` should be `options: {` and the respective closing bracket should be corrected. Also in the dinner array you're missing an "l" in label. Try fixing that and see if you manage to do what you want

Comment: Okay i made changes to the syntax but still not solved

Comment: @ravibagul91 but if i do this i'll have to write the component again and there in the<Select options = ... /> i can mention this.state.options[]. Is there a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my solution for you :

App.js

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories: [
        {
          name: "Breakfast",
          options: [
            { label: "Location 1", value: 1 },
            { label: "Location 2", value: 2 },
            { label: "Location 3", value: 3 },
            { label: "Location 4", value: 4 },
            { label: "Location 5", value: 5 },
            { label: "Location 6", value: 6 }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "dinner",
          options: [
            { label: "Venue 1", value: 1 },
            { label: "Venue 2", value: 1 },
            { label: "Venue 3", value: 1 },
            { label: "Venue 4", value: 1 },
            { label: "Venue 5", value: 1 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.categories.map(cat => (
          <Dropdown options={cat.options} title={cat.name} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

i have recreated your state because you cannot create a array inside array ! you need object for that.
so state has a categories array which has name and options.

Dropdown.js

```
    import React from "react";

const Dropdowm = ({ options, title }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <select>
      {options.map(option => (
        <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>
);

export default Dropdowm;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hellman-cyqyv)

Comment: Hey thanks for a detailed solution, your answer cleared some of my concepts but i'm still having a little trouble. so if i want to call the dropdown in the breakfast page it should show breakfast 1, breakfast 2, etc. and the same with dinner page i.e dinner 1, dinner 2, etc . Sorry i'm very new to react js so bear with me

Comment: Yes you can filter your array using name in each page like this : `this.state.categories.filter(cat=>cat.name=[your value])`

Comment: so where should i declare both the arrays ? in the dropdown component or somewhere else ? Here you have declared in the app component which is fine, but for me what do you think i should do ?

Comment: @okaycharm I suggest  you to use  global state management like redux,mobx... this will help you hold  all your app state in one file which is called a store, so you can share this state to all your component.

Comment: I'm thinking to use the redux part after some time because i've yet understand it properly. But is there an other way by using static props. Meaning is it possible to create an option.js which stores both arrays and when i call the dropdown i can just use <Select options={this,breakfast} or {this.dinenr}>. Can that happen? As of now i need to get the static part done for a demo and when i'm dealing with data i'll integrate redux to it

Comment: @okaycharm yes you can do with exporting the array and importing it in any component.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to return in render method. The best option would be to create a component that returns a dropdown list and pass the dropdowns data from the class in which you want to display the dropdown.

Comment: i have put up a dropdown part in the render
return(
      <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <Select options = { } />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
can you suggest me how should call the dropdown in two diiferent pages with two different option menus

Comment: You can find here a lot of usefull thinks about react and options: https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-select.html